# Puritanism on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I post this because [my question was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56518908/revisions) because I used the word "stupid" two times. "Stupid".

And the word was not intended to offend anyone, as you can see in the context of the previous link.

I read [this Meta Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites), and ok, I agree, vulgar language should be avoided. But "Stupid"? Used in that way? I don't know, let me know, maybe I'm wrong.

PS: Quoting George Carlin, I want a list :D

EDIT: I think the [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](http://Should%20I%20remove%20'fluff'%20when%20editing%20questions?) question is not a duplicate of my question, because in my opinion there's a prevention against "bad" words used as intensifiers.

Comment: Having unnecessary statements like "the usual stupid default icon" instead of "the default icon" does at least not improve your post.

Comment: Note that edits like this often happens because words throw simple quality control mechanisms, such as SmokeDetector, FireAlarm, or SEDE queries looking for keywords to identify bad posts. While I can't find it on MetaSmoke, Bonfire is currently down so I can't see if it popped up there.

Comment: @ErikA: so there's a list! And "stupid" could be on the list? I want the list :D

Comment: The default icon was designed by an UX artist who spend 8 hours on it to get it right. Calling it "stupid" at least offends them.

Comment: @gnat: People, seriously, you're out.

Comment: @rene: I think your comment is an offense to UX Designer's intelligence.

Comment: I might underestimate how long it takes to create an icon. I certainly have respect for these professionals and the products they deliver. None of which I find stupid. Not sure where you make up that I'm offending the intelligence of those pros'.

Comment: Well, you seem to be set on disregarding the effort of other users. I was editing your post to make it better, but it looks like you take it personally and prefer to go back to a worse version. The screenshot was helpful because it allowed users to have all the information without having to go another post (which could be deleted at later point, rendering the question less useful for future visitors). The "EDIT" line I removed because those shouldn't be added. Posts should read naturally. Good luck, I'm out.

Comment: @rene: do you *really* think I said that icon is `stupid` because I don't like it, or I think it's bad, or I think it's useless? Now you're offfending your and my intelligence.

Comment: At least we achieved that. Someone had to be offended here.

Comment: @yivi: the screenshot is useless, there's the link. And the link is to the editing history, so can't be removed. So I'm following your suggestion and remove fluff.

Comment: @MarcoSulla It's not just a list, but heuristic algorithms. This may not have triggered them, but avoiding words like that altogether allows us to more easily identify questions like _this entire site is stupid_. Also remember the site is international and for a wide audience, with wide cultural differences in what is and what's not offensive.

Comment: I've already explained how it is not useful. Apparently you didn't read it. Sorry, I said I was out, and here I am. Now I'm truly out. I'm going to buy an aquarium and some fishes to feed, seems more productive.

Comment: @yivi: if you don't want to reply in a costructive way, you can say nothing, you know? Your comments are fluffy.

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I probably wouldn't have bothering editing.

But it seems like a noisy comments that do nothing to communicate your problem (*"Well, it seems stupid"*, *"the usual stupid default icon"*) and are worth removing from a post.

Not because they used the "stupid" word You could have said "silly", "dumb", "strange"; and it would still be unnecessary fluff, IMO.

What I'm trying to say is that it is perfectly reasonable for someone to edit that out on grounds of being unnecessary, and not because of some sort of crusade against vulgar language.

I don't believe it was a bad edit. Your question is improved by removing that. You can disagree and rollback if you want, but frankly I see no reason to.

Saying something is stupid is an opinion. Nothing wrong with that, but the way you presented that opinion in your question doesn't help in any way.

At most, it can open up the post to an argument about if it's actually stupid or not. So **it can't help, and can hinder**. Better to remove it directly.

Comment: I rolled back and he rolled back again...

Comment: Well, they probably shouldn't engage in a rollback war. Again, you can rollback. It's your post. But why? The post is better this way.

Comment: Do you think I can rollback again so?

Comment: I believe you shouldn't, but it's up to you.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: I only see the edit, then your rollback. No other rollbacks from the editors side. The current edit is from me and fixed something unrelated to the discussion. Rolling that back is possible, but I don't see any reason to revert to wrong grammar.

Comment: It's not a bit oppressive? I mean, it can be superfluous, but there's lot of people that do unnecessary complicated question, that I read and ask to my self "What's the point"? No one touches them. I could added some unnecessary information like my CPU model and I'm sure no one would be edit it.

Comment: Actually, the _"usual stupid icon"_ line is still there. I believe the question would be better without that.

Comment: You feel it's "oppressive" but only because you think this is related to the use of the word "stupid", and because someone believes it's "vulgar". The problem is not that, the problem is that it's distracting from your question and making your post worse.

Comment: Well, I didn't rolled back it. Someone else did, probably the author itself, since I don't see the rollback anymore

Comment: Even if I added information about my CPU will distract from the real answer, but I'm sure no one will edited it.

Comment: @Marco You can be sure about many things, and yet be wrong. I edit irrelevant information from posts all the time. Logically, users are more careful when removing technical information that could conceivably have an impact on the question than irrelevant and noisy opinions.

Comment: They are not opinions, they are intensifiers. I prefer people like @BDL that corrected my poor English.

Comment: The [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520965/how-can-i-implement-hotkeys-into-my-discord-bot) for example. IMHO `I am wondering how I might go about adding keypress detection to my Discord bot.` could be replaced by `I would add keypress detection to my Discord bot.`. Three hours and no one edited it.

Comment: Marco, maybe you feel that way because English is not your native tongue (it is not mine either), but saying something is stupid **is an opinion**. Nothing wrong with that, but the way you present that opinion in your question doesn't help in any way. At most, it can open up the post to an argument about if it's actually stupid or not. So it can't help, and can hinder. Better to remove it.

Comment: Do you think I really think an icon is stupid? C'mon, is an intensifier.

Comment: You are using it wrong. You can learn, or insist on using it wrong and get your posts improved by other users.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @MarcoSulla Another point: SO strives to be a _professional_ q and a site, collecting useful information for future users. It is not a forum. Ideally, entries should look like something from a textbook: impersonal and somewhat formal.

Comment: @ModusTollens: link me the FAQ that says that.

Comment: `You are using it wrong`: you're not argumentign. Explain me why I'm using wrong that intensifier.

Comment: Marco, you came to ask a question, or to be told you are right? Because it's starting to look the latter. You should be open to accept that your preconceptions are not correct.

Comment: @MarcoSulla https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/204841

Comment: @MarcoSulla One quote: "Stack Exchange creates communities that draw in experts in particular fields who are interested in communicating and learning at a professional level. This results in writing quality being an important aspect of the site."

Comment: yivi, I'm discussing. You can counterargument my arguments. I'm discussing with no "stupid" word, moreover. So I think you can counterargument my counterargument. And I allow you to use "stupid" word if you want.

Comment: @ModusTollens: this is not a FAQ. So I have also to read the entire Meta do know how to post? Please link me a FAQ.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Ah geez. Do you want help or do you want to push your agenda? Anyway, good luck. I'm out.

Comment: And no one replied me to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385911/puritanism-on-stack-overflow#comment702319_385913). I think it's a good example of double standards.

Comment: @ModusTollens: I want help, and I want to know in which FAQ is written I have to use a professional language like I'm writing a book. Because in that case I have to rewrite all the answers and questions I've done in the past.

Comment: @MarcoSulla I don't want to be unfriendly, but since you do not seem to be open to suggestions I don't want to invest more time, sorry.

Comment: @ModusTollens: IMHO it's you that are deliberating avoiding my question. My question is really specific and you don't want to reply to it. So I think you're free to not respond me if don't know the answer, but please, don't say I'm not collaborative.